# How to clear the data in a Power BI Report when publishing it to multiple clients via DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

We are building a generic Power BI Reporting suite for a product. Every time we commit the PBIX file to Source Control our DevOps project publishes the report to multiple workspaces, clears the SQL Connection, and reattaches it to the SQL database for each particular client. We then trigger a dataset refresh so that the report loads the data from it's own SQL database.

The problem is that the PBIX file committed to GIT contains the imported data from the LAST SQL data source it was connected to (usually our Dev SQL DB). Then when the report and dataset are published to each client the client will see this imported DEV data in their report for a period of 20 minutes or so until the dataset has refreshed, which is a security risk and confusing for the user.

I found this workaround using PowerQuery as an example, however I am really hoping for a more robust solution.
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Another-way-to-clear-fetched-data-from-PBIX-files/m-p/686627

How can we "clear" the imported data in the PBIX file so that when we publish to each client it is completely empty and just reloads that clients data?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a Powerbi API?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_deleterows

The ideal situation would be to be able to publish pbit instead of pbix (which contains data). Unfortunately, this is not allowed. If you can, vote for this or a similar idea.

https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=b8928e24-3a1a-4a21-89d0-29fab9454a3c

Comment: Yes, we are using the PowerBI API to change the datasource connection and refresh. However there is that 20 min period where the REPORT contains the old data before it is refreshed from the datasource it seems. I'll look into those links, thanks.